# android.icu.text.DecimalFormat resets monetary separators

Tags: android, locale, icu

First of all, like the title says, this is about `android.icu.text.DecimalFormat`, and not `java.text.DecimalFormat`.

I'm using `DecimalFormat` to get `decimalFormatSymbols.monetaryGroupingSeparator` and `decimalFormatSymbols.monetaryDecimalSeparator`, and then use them to format amount input from the user.

`DecimalFormat` also has a `withCurrency` input, which from I see, shouldn't affect the monetary separators.

But, for some locales (`en_SE` and `en_DK`) and currencies (EUR), it does change the monetary separators.
As you can see, these are english locales for countries in EU which do not have EUR as currency.

From what I see we have the following cases:

| English | EU | EUR | locale | set EUR | set GBP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | X | X | en_AT,BE,DE,FI | `,` and `.` already | `,` and `.` already |
| X | X |  | en_DK,SE | X | WORKS |
| X |  | X | can't find locale | - | - |
| X |  |  | en_CA,GB,US,ZA | WORKS | WORKS |
|  | X | X | fr_FR | WORKS | WORKS |
|  | X |  | ro_RO, dk_DK, se_SE | WORKS | WORKS |
|  |  | X | ca_AD | WORSK | WORKS |
|  |  |  | nb_NO | WORKS | WORKS |

So let's assume we have this class

```
class DecimalFormatWrapper(private val locale: Locale) {
    val decimalFormat: DecimalFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale) as DecimalFormat

    val monetaryGroupingSeparator: Char
        get() = decimalFormat.decimalFormatSymbols.monetaryGroupingSeparator

    val monetaryDecimalSeparator: Char
        get() = decimalFormat.decimalFormatSymbols.monetaryDecimalSeparator

    fun withCurrency(currencyCode: String) {
        Log.d("DF-S", "[$monetaryGroupingSeparator] / [$monetaryDecimalSeparator]")
        decimalFormat.withCurrency(Currency.getInstance(currencyCode))
        Log.d("DF-E", "[$monetaryGroupingSeparator] / [$monetaryDecimalSeparator]")
    }
}
```

And we use it like this:

```
DecimalFormatWrapper(en_DK).withCurrency("EUR")
// DF-S: [.] / [,]
// DF-E: [,] / [.]

DecimalFormatWrapper(en_DK).withCurrency("GBP")
// DF-S: [.] / [,]
// DF-E: [.] / [,]

DecimalFormatWrapper(en_SE).withCurrency("EUR")
// DF-S: [ ] / [,]
// DF-E: [,] / [.]

DecimalFormatWrapper(en_SE).withCurrency("GBP")
// DF-S: [ ] / [,]
// DF-E: [ ] / [,]

DecimalFormatWrapper(en_ZA).withCurrency("EUR")
// DF-S: [ ] / [,]
// DF-E: [ ] / [,]

DecimalFormatWrapper(ro_RO).withCurrency("EUR")
// DF-S: [.] / [,]
// DF-E: [.] / [,]

// etc
```

My question is: is there any reason for this behaviour, or is this a bug in the `DecimalFormat`/`NumberFormat` implementation?